# .NET 5: "runtime-deps" vs "aspnet" docker image for aspnet API

Tags: asp.net, docker, kubernetes

In a microservice architecture on AKS I'm moving all "worker" services (scaled by ServiceBus messages using [KEDA](https://github.com/kedacore/keda), including scale-to-zero) to self-contained compilation and the `runtime-deps` docker image, since they benefit from faster startup-times provided by AOT compilation.

Are there any drawbacks when doing the same to aspnet APIs? Or does the `aspnet` docker image provide anything on top? For context, they are stateless and multi-tenant, no data is held in memory.

Comment: just an update, aspnet runs fine as well self-contained. i'd still like to know if there's a difference between running an aspnet-runtime container and a self-contained one.i guess i'll give the answer shortly.